# Xcode 5 iOS 7 - subviews have lost positioning constraints

Tags: layout, ios7, autolayout, xcode5

I was moving stuff around to get it to work in iOS 7, then the machine crashed (not unusual with a new Xcode installation). Now the subviews don't have their positioning constraints any more. Is there a way to get them back? Don't care if it's just the default constraints, right now elements are all over the place. If not, is there a way to get everything into auto layout? Some elements appear to be spring and strut aligned, others are auto layout. Probably the crash messed it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of the main edit window is a toolbar with something that looks like a tie fighter.

```
┣●┫
```

Click that, then in the menu, select "Reset to Suggested Constraints".